# My Json class Takes a lot of time to load

Tags: android, json, android-json, jsonparser

I have created my own JSON class. But, I am having a problem when the internet is slow.
When the internet is slow or there is a problem with mysql server. It takes a lot of time and never retrieve data. So, I would like to cancel the connection. 
How can I modify my JSON class to do so. Or, Do I need to do it in my Async<> to do so.

My JSON class :

```
  public class JSONParser {

public String ret ;
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> pairs)
{
    UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
    try
    {
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        int timeoutConnection = 500;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeoutConnection);

        int timeoutSocket = 500;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        if (pairs != null)
        {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs,"UTF-8"));
        }

        HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (httpEntity != null)
        {
            ret = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            return new JSONObject(ret.substring(ret.indexOf("{"), ret.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current timeoutConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amjad, Parser class has no issue in this case. As you mentioned if the internet is slow then receiving time itself takes long time.  Why don't you try retrofit. It will return you exact model after response success. Also that has cancel the request at anytime. You can [refer this link](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)